# Is there a way to enable/disable button depending on condition of multiple selectbox?

Tags: javascript, flask

In my Flask app, I have a page with 5 selectbox:

```
<select onchange="disableBtn()" id="first" name="select_first">
      <option value="option1">Select an option</option>
      {% for each in list %}
      <option value="{{each}}">{{each}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I would like to enable/disable the button if only one of the selectbox has an option selected.

```
function disableBtn() {
    var select = document.getElementById("first");
    var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "option1") {
        document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

How could I use the same function for all the boxes? I tried with multiple if but it works only for the first.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a listener for the change event to all select elements, which checks whether an acceptable option was selected for one of the select boxes.

With `querySelectorAll` you query all select boxes.
With `some` you iterate over an array and check if a condition is true for at least one element.

```
const buttonElem = document.getElementById('button');
const selectElems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="select_"]'));
selectElems.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('change', evt => {
    buttonElem.disabled = !selectElems.some(e => e.value !== 'option1');
  });
});
```

If the button should only be activated if exactly one select box was selected, the code is as follows.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const buttonElem = document.getElementById('button');
  const selectElems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="select_"]'));
  selectElems.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('change', evt => {
      buttonElem.disabled = selectElems.filter(e => e.value !== 'option1').length !== 1;
    });
  });
});
```

All select boxes are filtered for which "option1" was not selected. If the length of the resulting array is not one, the button is disabled.
The code is embedded in a listener that waits until the entire document is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution but it works if select 2 or more option in different selectbox. I would just one select option

Comment: Sorry, didn't read properly. I've expanded my answer.

Comment: With your second solution the button is always disable

Comment: That should not be. All select boxes are filtered for which "option1" was not selected. If the length of the resulting array is not one, the button is disabled.

Comment: I know, I tried your code in online editor and it works but in my code I don't know why it doesn't. Could this be due to Flask?

Comment: No, the code only refers to html and javascript. The part generated with jinja is negligible. How do you embed the code? It could be related to the timing of execution.

Comment: I used **<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/sections.js')}}"></script>** to embed the js code

Comment: OK. Updated my answer again. The code is embedded in a listener that waits until the entire document is loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry but this solution doesn't work either, I don't understand what the problem is and it's driving me crazy

Comment: Let's continue in chat.